# Facebook Graph APi - Retrieve all comment where i'm mentioned

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Would like to know if there is a smart way to retrieve all comment where a page has been mentioned (@mypage)?. Up to now I call /me/notifications and parse all type of notifications, there is something I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about posts where the page is mentioned or tagged (in which case, the /page-id/tagged endpoint would help)? If you're asking about comments where the page is tagged, your current way might be the only option. Ref - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments

Comment: @deesarus Thanks a lot, i'm trying to extract comments where my page is tagged, so I'll continue to parse /me/notifications. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed to @deesarus, there is no a dedicated API to extract comments where a page is tagged. Only way is to parse /page/notification.